# Breakpoints can't be seen when using C interoperability

Tags: c, fortran, breakpoints, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to debug a static library written in C using a Fortran program and the two are linked using Fortran's C interoperability.  I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows.

However, when inserting a breakpoint in C and building a new .lib file and linking it to the main program, the Fortran application does not see the breakpoint. Here is an example for simplicity:

The C code in static library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f()
{
printf("Hello from C \n");

printf("Before breake point \n");
printf("At the breake point \n"); // breakpoint is inserted here
printf("After breake point \n");
}
```

The Fortran code:

```
program test
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
implicit none

interface
subroutine f() bind (C)
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
end subroutine f
end interface

call f
pause
end program test
```

The .lib file was created in debug mode and the Fortran code is being run in debug mode as well. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

(Please note that the above example is for illustration only and not the actual code I am trying to debug)

Comment: It's unclear what toolchain you are using, but since you mention `.lib` files I suppose it is for Windows.  Perhaps things are different there, but in the world I'm used to, breakpoints are not an attribute of compiled code, library or otherwise.  Rather, breakpoints are an aspect of a debugging session -- you set them up at some point during the session, and they do not persist past the end of the session (though one session may consist of many runs of the program being debugged).

Comment: Yes, it is Windows. I am using visual studio 2013

Comment: It's been a long time since I did any Windows programming, but back in the day, Visual Studio was no exception to the paradigm I described in my first comment.  You seem to be assuming that breakpoints are somehow built into the `.lib` file, but that's not how it works on Unix, nor how it ever worked on Windows in my now somewhat remote experience.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Also learn [ask].

Comment: @Olaf, you better read the question before start commenting!

Comment: Tell that @JohnBollinger, too. He seems to share my opinion. **You** OTOH better take the [tour] and get some manners.

Comment: @Anas! to make things simple, does a C program see the breakpoint in the lib? I mean you first buil the lib and link the C prog against the lib. That will confirm or infirm the diagnostic of @JohnBollinger.

Answer (score 0):

So the .lib file needs .pdb code to be generated.  The default Visual studio behavior creates these called vcxx.pdb, which can be overwritten by subsequent builds.  This can be re-named in the .lib build.

Once the code has been bound into a .dll, then the DLL needs debugging information to be available.  This is part of the .dll build process.

Finally if all those have been fixed, and the breakpoint still doesn't work then insert a DebugBreak() into the code to force a debugger break.